# Python: I want two while loops generate two

Tags: python

I'm new with Python and programming in general. I have a list and I want a variable taking each value of the list progressively in a loop. Which instruction should I use to extrapolate the single values of the list?

```
b = [-100, -50, -150, -100, -100, -100, -50]
```

Comment: I think you're looking for a [`for`](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) loop, but I can't undertstand your question's title : *I want two while loops generate two* ??

Comment: try to improve your question, is not clear what you want. What do you mean by "extrapolate the single values"? Also the code as it is written b is a list with just one value, -650, did you mean to make b a list with 7 integers?

Comment: Go through the [python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) - it will give you the fundamentals of the language.

Answer (score 4):

```
b = [-100, -50, -150, -100, -100, -100, -50]
for x in b:
    print(x)
```

This will print:

```
-100
-50
-150
-100
-100
-100
-50
```

Comment: that last one is a little out of place, I know it is fun but you should remove it, is just spreading a bad practice.